# how to use KeyValue in KeyPress event in C#

Tags: c#, keypress

In key press event we can use `KeyChar` property and in `KeyDown` event we can use `KeyValue`.
I need to use `KeyValue` and `KeyChar`  property in `KeyPress` event. How can I do it?

Comment: You can use `KeyChar` but not `KeyValue` in `KeyPress` event.. The thing is, what you want to do ??

Answer (score 5):

You can not access `KeyValue` in **`KeyPress event`**. but you can use **`KeyDown event`** instead. then you can use **`KeyValue`** and then **`e.KeyCode.ToString()`** to get `KeyChar`.

> in **KeyDown** event : `e.KeyCode.ToString() = KeyChar`

example:

```
Private void YourControl_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) 
{
    var keyChar = e.KeyCode.ToString()
    var keyValue = e.KeyValue
}
```

Comment: tanks. but there is difference between keychar and keycode results in many languages.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think you can. Consider that a single KeyPress might require the user pressing just one key, or more than one; and the same key being pressed might result in different characters firing in the KeyPress event. Pressing the "a" key on the keyboard might result in the characters "a", "A", or no character at all (ctrl-A), depending on whether caps lock is on, or the shift key or control key is pressed. In short, the KeyPress event does valuable preprocessing for you, and you cannot get the original information back from before the preprocessing.

Comment: ok. but keypress event and KeyChar property can handle many languages. and it can show if you pressed 'a' or shift+'a'="A".